# How to remove country/state names from MKMapview

Tags: iphone, ipad, mkmapview

I want to remove country / state names from `MKMapview` in iPhone. Means I need only blank map view without any name on it. Is this possible with `MKMapview` or any other third party maps.

I want to use this functionality with `MKMapTypeStandard` map type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `MKMapViews` property mapType `MKMapTypeSatellite`. Setting this type you will see a map without any names on it. See the docs:
[MkMapView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)

Code:

```
self.map.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me is this possible with MKMapTypeStandard maptype. I want to use this functionality with MKMapTypeStandard.

Comment: I doupt this is possible with MKMapView