# Remove or hide countries names from MKMapview

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

the question is already asked, but no solution yet,

is there any way to remove or hide the countries name from ios map?

help please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695934/how-to-remove-country-state-names-from-mkmapview

Comment: I need to use MKMapTypeStandard, the solution suggested in this question is to use MKMapTypeSatellite only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove country/ State names from mkmapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695934/how-to-remove-country-state-names-from-mkmapview)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not currently possible to modify `MKMapView` to remove the country names while using `MKMapTypeStandard`.

However there are alternative open source maps available which allow you to do this like Mapbox: https://www.mapbox.com/help/customizing-streets-layer/